# Выход текста за грани родительского блока

Tags: react-native

React Native. Текст выходит за грани родительского блока.

```
// View -> ScrollView -> ListView -> TouchableOpacity (Если это имеет значение)
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
    <Image style={{width: 100, heigth: 100}}/>
    <View>
        <Text> // style flex:1, но это не влияет на проблему
            Текст переносится, но немного 
            за гранью родительского View
        </Text>
        // ... Ещё немного элементов, не суть.
    </View>
</View>
```

Проблема с `flexDirection: "row"`, но без него (возможно) не получится расположить элементы так как мне это нужно.

P.S. Родительский View не выходит за грани экрана, как это делает текст.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась заданием flex > 0 для родительского блока.